# Data validation attributes displaying incorrect error message

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

I have MVVM WPF application, where model properties are decorated with validation attributes Required and custom attribute, that checks if value already exist. Validation is performed on LostFocus.
If I enter data (TextBox) that does not satisfy first attribute, correct error message is displayed, but if I modify this data in way, that does not satisfy second attribute, error message from first attribute is still displayed.
If I enter first bad value, then correct value and then second bad value, correct error message is displayed.
I also tried to perform validation not using attributes, but checking value in property setter and throwing exception, everything works fine.
Where can be error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in implementation of IValueConverter used to display error messages as ToolTips of controls.

Not working:

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorToolTipStyle" TargetType="Control">
  <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource ValidationErrorsToString}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Style>
```

Working:

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorToolTipStyle" TargetType="Control">
  <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Style>
```